# EntityType 'Breed' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

It may looks like a copy of already asked question.
i have checked all the solutions but my problem is non-logical.

```
public class Breed
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    int id { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
}
```

Error Kamdhenu.Models.Breed: : EntityType 'Breed' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Breeds: EntityType: EntitySet 'Breeds' is based on type 'Breed' that has no keys defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the properties as `public`. Without specifier they are `private` by default and EF won't recognize and map private properties:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
```