# EntityType 'Account' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: entity-framework

I have Two entity class:

```
namespace PowerSupply.Domain
{
    [Table("Accounts")]
    public class Account
    {
        public int Id;
        public string CompanyName;
        public float Interval;
    }
}
```

And

```
namespace PowerSupply.Domain
{
   public class ContactInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string mobileNo { get; set; }
        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my DbContext :

```
public class PowerSupplyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public PowerSupplyDBContext() : base("PowerSupplyDatabase")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Account> Acounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContactInfo> ContactInfo { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to enable-migration the I am getting the following error:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

PowerSupply.Persistance.Facade.Account: : EntityType 'Account' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Acounts: EntityType: EntitySet 'Acounts' is based on type 'Account' that has no keys defined.
```

I studied and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036392/entitytype-breed-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype) duplicate.
All property is set to public. Any idea?

Comment: the properties have no public getters and setters and no annotation.

Comment: My EF automatically picks up a `public int ID{get;set;}` so try using a all caps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `[Key]` annotation in `Id` property and don't forget getters and setters:

```
namespace PowerSupply.Domain
{
    [Table("Accounts")]
    public class Account
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string CompanyName {get; set;}
        public float Interval {get; set}
    }
}
```